# jquery change custom attribute status

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change a custom attribute and am having no luck. Am I missing something silly?

HTML:

```
    <div class="favorite" status="off">&#9734</div>
```

JQuery:

```
    $(".favorite").click(
        function(){
            var currentvalue = $(this).attr("status");
            if(currentvalue == "off"){
                $(this).html("&#9733;");
                $(this).attr("status") = "on";
            }else if (currentvalue == "on"){
                $(this).html("&#9734;");
                $(this).attr("status") = "off";
            }
        }
    );
```

I can change the star to filled in, but the status never changes to "on". What Am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use a setter version of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value)(pass the value to set as the second argument).

```
$(this).attr("status", 'on')
```